# Telegram photo bot

Tags: python, python-2.7, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm writing a telegram bot as a part of a larger project but i can't seem to get the bot to write a new file every time it downloads an image, instead it just overwrites the first image it recieved.

another problem i came across is that it downloads the images without the user typing /photo, i didn't mind it so lets call it a "feature" but if thats the reason please explain it to me

Thx in advance for the help

```
import logging
from telegram.ext import MessageHandler, Filters
from telegram.ext import Updater
import os
import os.path
import datetime
import sys
updater = Updater(token= 'omitted')
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%y_%H:%M,%S")

def start(bot, update):
    update.message.reply_text('Hello World!')

def hello(bot, update):
    update.message.reply_text(
        'Hello {}'.format(update.message.from_user.first_name))

def photo(bot, update):
    save_path = '/Users/barthofman/Desktop/grandtest/'
    file_id = update.message.photo[-1].file_id
    newFile = bot.getFile(file_id)
    newFile.download(os.path.join(save_path, time+'.jpg'))
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="download succesful")
    filename = (time+'jpg')
    with open(filename,"rb") as f:
        Jpegcontents = (f.read())
        if Jpegcontents.startswith(b"\xff\xd8") and Jpegcontents.endswith(b"\xff\xd9"):
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Valid Image")
        if not Jpegcontents.startswith(b"\xff\xd8") and Jpegcontents.endswith(b"\xff\xd9"):
           os.system("rm ",filename)



photo_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.photo, photo)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(photo_handler)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('hello', hello))

updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
updater.stop()
```

Comment: I highly suggest you generate a new authentication token. They're meant to be kept private.

Comment: shouldn't you set the time variable inside def photo?

Comment: ...holy shit you are right, totally missed that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Time variable should have been inside the "def photo" 
like so

```
  import logging
from telegram.ext import MessageHandler, Filters
from telegram.ext import Updater
import os
import os.path
import datetime
import sys
updater = Updater(token= 'omitted')
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%y_%H:%M,%S")

def start(bot, update):
    update.message.reply_text('Hello World!')

def hello(bot, update):
    update.message.reply_text(
        'Hello {}'.format(update.message.from_user.first_name))

def photo(bot, update):
    save_path = '/Users/barthofman/Desktop/grandtest/'
    file_id = update.message.photo[-1].file_id
    newFile = bot.getFile(file_id)
    newFile.download(os.path.join(save_path, time+'.jpg'))
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="download succesful")
    filename = (time+'jpg')
    with open(filename,"rb") as f:
        Jpegcontents = (f.read())
        if Jpegcontents.startswith(b"\xff\xd8") and Jpegcontents.endswith(b"\xff\xd9"):
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Valid Image")
        if not Jpegcontents.startswith(b"\xff\xd8") and Jpegcontents.endswith(b"\xff\xd9"):
           os.system("rm ",filename)



photo_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.photo, photo)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(photo_handler)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('hello', hello))

updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
updater.stop()
```

Thanks to  redFIVE its solved
Grats